# Checking the connectivity of a VPN using C/C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, connection

Is there a fairly robust method of checking the connectivity to a VPN on a timed basis (every N minutes) using C/C++ on Windows? In python, I simply pinged a host and read the reply - although this method works I would prefer to use something that is less of a hack.

Comment: Pinging a known host is the correct method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about a windows VPN connection (rather than something like OpenVPN) you can enumerate the current Remote Access (RAS) connections using [RasEnumConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and you can get the status of the connection using [RasGetConnectStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly could write your own service that loads automatically and can be managed via services.msc, I would not recommend wasting time on it.

For this simple purpose you only need a task scheduler (schtasks.exe for example) and a primitive check program.

I have one implemented for similar purposes in Perl, it checks internet connectivity every minute with a list of URLS, and tries to save information about modem status from another list of URLs. It also logs everything it does

http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/svn/script/cable/

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in another answer, you can call

```
    DWORD RasGetLinkStatistics(
  __in     HRASCONN hRasConn,
  __in     DWORD dwSubEntry,
  __inout  RAS_STATS *lpStatistics);
```

to get enough information

- connection speed,
- amount of data sent/received,
- time connected

about your connection. Read more about it on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).